# Not able to slide anything on the touch bar in macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I am not able to slide/scroll through the touch bar in MacBook pro. When trying to slide while adjusting brightness or sound then It shows a control like in the image below on the screen. what to do?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the Zoom accessibility feature enabled on your Touch Bar.

Dragging causes you to scroll the Touch Bar rather than dragging the control underneath. To drag a control, pause for the duration of the circle, then drag.

Disable it in System Preferences → Accessibility → Zoom → Touch Bar.

[How to use accessibility features with Touch Bar on your MacBook Pro - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207258)

Comment: Perfect, Work like a charm. Thank you so much. Now it is feeling so good. 